# Intermediate container is not always created

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This question is for demonstrating docker and how it works, the following  is the dockerfile content

```
FROM node:7
ADD node.js /node.js
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "node.js"]
```

and the node.js file is exist in the same directory, the question is why there is no intermediate container created for step#2?

```
~/demos/docker$docker build -t nodeapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM node:7
7: Pulling from library/node
ad74af05f5a2: Pull complete 
2b032b8bbe8b: Pull complete 
a9a5b35f6ead: Pull complete 
3245b5a1c52c: Pull complete 
afa075743392: Pull complete 
9fb9f21641cd: Pull complete 
3f40ad2666bc: Pull complete 
49c0ed396b49: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:af5c2c6ac8bc3fa372ac031ef60c45a285eeba7bce9ee9ed66dad3a01e29ab8d
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:7
 ---> d9aed20b68a4
Step 2/3 : ADD node.js /node.js
 ---> 44c4486c7b32
Step 3/3 : ENTRYPOINT ["node", "node.js"]
 ---> Running in c9291d1209b0
Removing intermediate container c9291d1209b0
 ---> cfb9beed3592
Successfully built cfb9beed3592
Successfully tagged nodeapp:latest
```

**EDIT**

For example see the following example from [this lnk](https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612) specifically this where COPY caused to create intermediate container

```
Step 4 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/  ---> 334d93a151ee Removing
intermediate container a678c817e467
```

And from [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) where

```
ADD Execute-MyCmdlet.ps1 c:\example\
```

resulted

```
Step 4/5 : ADD Execute-MyCmdlet.ps1 c:\example\  ---> a955b2621c31
Removing intermediate container b825593d39fc
```

So for ADD and COPY the instructions caused intermediate container to be created then removed.

Comment: I think I see what you're question is getting at now. I updated my answer to include an explanation for what you're seeing. The change that I believe caused this change was released in April 2019. The first link you posted is from 2016, and the example output in the official documentation has not been changed since at least 2017. I imagine that it's a pretty inconsequential difference for most people, so probably not much urgency to update the docs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for an intermediate container to be spun up for step 2/3. Docker will add the file `node.js` to the image layer without starting a temporary container.

This build follows these steps:

1. download the image, creating layer ID `d9aed20b68a4`
2. add `node.js` to create image layer ID `44c4486c7b32`
3. start container `c9291d1209b0` from image ID `44c4486c7b32` and set the entry point
4. save the result of step (3) as the final image layer ID `cfb9beed3592`

You will see the same thing if you use a `COPY` in the dockerfile, instead of `ADD`. `COPY` is usually the preferred command to move files into the image, but `ADD` is ok too (just don't `ADD` a URL, as that pattern is discouraged).

**Edit**: 
The link you included in your update is from 2016. Back then, Docker used a special 'helper image' that ran a custom binary inside of the container in order to execute `COPY/ADD` directives. That was changed fairly recently (April 2019) to allow the build to directly manipulate the file system. More information can be found in the [release notes](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/releases/tag/v0.5.0), but I'll add the relevant section here:

> **FileOp**
>   LLB supports new operation FileOp allowing built-in file operations during build like copying files, creating new files or directories and removing files. Previously ADD/COPY commands used a helper image that ran a custom binary inside a container, now these commands use FileOp directly. This allows better performance and use of these commands in air-gapped environments without preloading the helper image, as well as fixing issues reported with the helper image implementation.

Comment: OP should read [Dockerfile best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/), more specifically the `ADD or COPY` paragraph, where it is specified that `COPY` is preferred unless you specifically need features provided by `ADD`.

Comment: @Zeitounator, it's not about what's the best practice more than why the intermediate container hasn't been created. 
Please see the update.